# How to read a single character with getchar in C?

Tags: c, arrays, switch-statement, getchar

I'm creating a menu driven program in C where I have to ask for user input, then use only the first character of the input in my program. In addition to the code below, I've also tried `#define MAX_CHAR 1` and using it instead of `EOF` in the `while` loop, among other things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_menu();
void uppercase(char *string); 

int main()
{
    char i = 0, c = 0;
    char selection[0];

    print_menu();

        while((c = getchar()) != EOF)  
        {
            selection[i++] = c;
            selection[i] = '\0';  //insert NULL at end of string
            uppercase(selection);

            switch(selection[i])
            {
                case 'c':
                uppercase(selection);
                printf("%s\n", selection );
                print_menu();
                break;

                case 'X':
                printf("The program is exiting, Schuss!\n" );
                exit(0);

                default:
                printf("\nYou entered: %s\n", selection);
                print_menu();
                break;
           }

        }
 return 0;
}

void print_menu()  //gives code for menu
{
    printf("Select a menu item and hit enter: \n" );
    printf("C)  Convert the string to uppercase\n");
    printf("M)  Display this menu\n");
    printf("X)  Exit the program\n");
}
void uppercase(char *string) 
{
  int c = 0;

  while (string[c] != '\0')
  {
    if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z')
    {
      string[c] = string[c] - 32;
     }
     c++;
  }

}
```

If I type `Yes!` when running the program, I expect the output to be 
`You entered: Y`and then the menu prints. 
Currently the output is

```
You entered: Y
Select a menu item and hit enter: 
C)  Convert the string to uppercase
M)  Display this menu
X)  Exit the program

You entered: YE
Select a menu item and hit enter: 
C)  Convert the string to uppercase
M)  Display this menu
X)  Exit the program

You entered: S
Select a menu item and hit enter: 
C)  Convert the string to uppercase
M)  Display this menu
X)  Exit the program

You entered: S!
Select a menu item and hit enter: 
C)  Convert the string to uppercase
M)  Display this menu
X)  Exit the program

You entered: 

Select a menu item and hit enter: 
C)  Convert the string to uppercase
M)  Display this menu
X)  Exit the program
^C
```

I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the `while` loop, haven't figured out how to fix it though. Eventually I'll have more menu items and cases. So for example, the user will enter `A` and it'll print `a` then print the menu again to wait for the next menu selection until the user enters 'X' to exit. Also, I do know there are two function calls for `uppercase` and that's intentional at this point.

EDIT: I'm wanting `getchar()` to read one character as it's designed to do. Then do whatever matches the case for that character. Then print the menu again (this part is included in each case statement). Then repeat from step 1 (which is "read one character").

I've changed my code to put `getchar()` outside the while loop and set the loop to `while(1)` instead which does result in reading only one character but also creates an infinite loop printing `You entered: B` and the menu. So that's progress, kind of.

Comment: `char selection[0];` is wrong. and `switch(selection[i])` --> `switch(*selection)`

Comment: I've tried with different sizes, and same result. I thought limiting the size of the array would work, so left it as-is since other sizes didn't work.

Comment: You want to read the entire line entered by the user and then only use the first character. `fgets` is suitable for reading a line of input.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. Only use spaces for indenting.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: while 'implicit conversion' might allow your posted code to run correctly, this line: `char i = 0 c = 0;` is trying to initialize a couple of `char` variables with `int` values.  Suggest using: `= '\0'` (a char) for the initializers.

Comment: regarding this line: `while((c = getchar()) != EOF) ` When reading from `stdin` will not see EOF unless the user enters the appropriate keystrokes.  The user is much more likely to enter a newline. Suggest the statement be: `while((c = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != c )`

Comment: this line: `char selection[0];` just defines a place holder, not any array of char. You might try: `char selection[ 1024 ];`  of course, the following `while()` loop should be checking to assure the array is not overflowed by the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to read a single character with `getchar` in C?

You can read ONLY a single character using `getchar`.

> I have to ask for user input, then use only the first character of the input in my program.

You can do that by reading an entire line and using only the first character of the line.

```
char line[100]; // Make it large enough.
while( fgets(line, 100, stdin) != NULL )
{
    uppercase(line);
    char selection = line[0];

    switch (selection)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rhymoid This way would probably work well if I were able to use the `toupper` function. I'm required to use my own `uppercase` function and that gives me "incompatible type" errors.

Comment: @Rhymoid, Oops!

Comment: @InertialOberserver Why weren't you able to use toupper? If it's really impossible, write your own toupper function is easy if you only use char type (see ASCII table)

Comment: @Fefux I did write a somewhat similar function, because that's part of my assignment. Also, the other functions I'll end up using are also using The same format as my 'uppercase' function so the errors would pop up there too. The format I'm using for my other functions is also 'void myFunction(char *string). Sorry about my formatting, I'm having a keyboard problem.

Comment: @R Sahu You're right, I should have said I want to stop reading characters after the first one is read.

Comment: @InertialObserver, wake up. Make up your mind :) You are saying one thing in the post and another thing in comments.

Comment: @R Sahu  I think I was tired and not being clear, lol. I'll edit the post and see if I can explain better, thank you!

Comment: @R Sahu Thank you! I didn't see your edit right away and this version works!

Answer (score 0):

How to read a single character with getchar in C?

Just in this way:

```
getchar();
```

By the way, you are overwriting some memory here:

```
char i = 0, c = 0;
char selection[0];  // What?! An array of 0 elements?!

...

    selection[i++] = c;    // Where are you storing the value?
    selection[i] = '\0';   // Same here
```

And note that after some while loops, your `i` variable will have a value of 12? 34? 1234?, because you don't initilize it to 0 before you do `selection[i++] = c`, each time you do it.

Comment: I believe that `array[0]` is actually an array of 1 since `[0]` is the location of the first element of the array? I could be wrong since I'm still getting a handle on how arrays work. Also, it does seem to store the value of the input though it does not limit that to storing only one which was what I was trying to accomplish with that setting.

Comment: `array[0]` results in a place holder, no actual area in an array

Answer (score 0):

even though the following code has no undefined behavior and does allow the user to input up to 128 characters, there is nothing in the OPs code, nor does this code that makes use of the first (up to) 4 characters

```
#include <stdio.h> // getchar(), prinf()
//#include <string.h>
//#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <ctype.h> // toupper()

void print_menu( void );
//void uppercase( char *string ); 

#define MAX_CHARS (128)

int main( void )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    int c;   // getchar() returns an int, not a char
    //char selection[0];
    char selection[ MAX_CHARS+1 ]; // +1 to allow for NUL terminator byte

    print_menu();

    while( i < MAX_CHARS && (c = getchar()) != EOF && 'X' != toupper(c) ) 
    {
        if( '\n' == c )  // ignore any newlines
            continue;

        selection[i++] = (char)toupper(c);
        selection[i] = '\0';  //insert NUL byte at end of string
        //uppercase(selection);

        switch(selection[i-1]) // -1 because 'i' is the termination byte
        {
            //case 'c':
            //    //uppercase(selection);
            //    printf("%s\n", selection );
            //    print_menu();
            //    break;

            //case 'X':
            //    printf("The program is exiting, Schuss!\n" );
            //    //exit(0);
            //    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
            //    break;

            default:
                printf("\nYou entered: %s\n", selection);
                print_menu();
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("The program is exiting, Schuss!\n" );
    //return 0; // not needed for 'main()' in modern C
} // end function: main


void print_menu()  //gives code for menu
{
    // note: C concatenates successive literal strings
    printf("Select a menu item and hit enter: \n" 
           "X)  Exit the program\n"
           "any other key appends to input, except newline\n");
} // end function: print_menu


//void uppercase(char *string) 
//{
//  int c = 0;

//  while (string[c] != '\0')
//  {
//    if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z')
//    {
//      string[c] = string[c] - 32;
//     }
//     c++;
//  }
//}
```